# list checkbox's for each separate question with its own unique id

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I can't get a list checkbox's for each separate question with its own unique id.

I would like to receive at each iteration only a list of checkboxes that belong to a certain div with a unique id.

```js
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            var questions = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = questions.map(question =>
                `<div class="question" id="${question.id}">
                    <div id="qustionText">${question.questionText}</div>
                    <div class="answers">${question.answers.map(answer =>
                    `<div id="${answer.id}"> <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="${answer.id}">` + answer.answerText).join('')}</div>
                    </div>`
            ).join('');
            console.log(questions);

        }
    };
    
      function getQuestions() {
        let questions = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
        let checkboxes;
        let questionCheckboxes = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
                let questionId = questions[i].id
                let quest = questions[i];
               checkboxes = quest.querySelectorAll(`#${CSS.escape(questionId)} input[type="checkbox"]`);
               for (let j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++) {
                   questionCheckboxes.push(checkboxes[j].value);
               }
        }
        return questionCheckboxes;
    }
```

```html
<div id="test" class="test"></div>
<div id="sendAnswersButton"></div>
```

But then I get a list of checkboxes from all questions at once.

```
let questionId = questions[i].id
let quest = questions[i];
checkboxes = quest.querySelectorAll(`#${CSS.escape(questionId)} input[type="checkbox"]`);
```

Comment: Looks like the structure you are creating there is faulty - I count four opening `<div>` tags, but only three closing `</div>`. You have not created multiple `.question` elements that are siblings of each other, but they are all _nested_ into each other.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am ashamed for such a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to loop through the the checkbox inputs within just a single question's DOM element at time. The `getQuestionCheckboxValues` function does just that.

The `setupQuestions` function demonstrates building the question divs from actual DOM elements rather than by parsing an HTML string -- which can be error-prone, as you have already discovered.

And note that using `id="checkbox"` on multiple elements on the same page will lead to sadness because each `id` must be unique to avoid undefined behavior by the browser.

```js
const myData = getParsedJson(); // Simulates incoming data
setupQuestions(myData); // Builds DOM elements

const q2_vals = getQuestionCheckboxValues("q2");

// Logs output
console.log("Question 2 checkbox values include:");
for(let val of q2_vals){
  console.log(`  ${val}`);
}


function getQuestionCheckboxValues(qId){
  const
    // Questions happen to use a data-id property instead of `id`
    quest = document.querySelector(`[data-qid=${qId}]`),

    // Selects elements by class within question, and converts to array
    cbArray = Array.from(quest.querySelectorAll(".checkbox")),

    // Defines an array containing checkbox values for this question
    values = cbArray.map(cb => cb.value);
  return values;
}


function setupQuestions(questions){
  const questionsDiv = document.getElementById("questionsContainer");
  for(let q of questions){
    const
      {id, questionText, answers} = q, // Uses "destructuring" to bind values

      // Defines new elements
      qDiv = document.createElement("div"),
      qTextDiv = document.createElement("div"),
      qAnswersDiv = document.createElement("div");

    // Configures new elements
    qDiv.classList.add("question");
    qTextDiv.classList.add("questionText");
    qAnswersDiv.classList.add("answers");
    qDiv.setAttribute("data-qid", q.id);
    qTextDiv.textContent = q.questionText;

    // Does the same for sub-elements within the answers div
    for(let a of q.answers){
      const
        {id, answerText} = a,
        aDiv = document.createElement("div"),
        checkbox = document.createElement("input");
      
      checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
      checkbox.classList.add("checkbox");
      checkbox.value = a.id;
      aDiv.setAttribute("data-aid", a.id);

      // Puts new elements into their parent elements
      aDiv.appendChild(checkbox); 
      aDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a.answerText));
      qDiv.appendChild(aDiv);
    }
    questionsDiv.appendChild(qDiv);
  }
}

function getParsedJson(){
  return [
    {
      id: "q1",
      questionText: "How many?",
      answers: [
        {id: "silly_answer", answerText: "34"},
        {id: "correct_answer", answerText: "42"}
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "q2",
      questionText: "Why?",
      answers: [
        {id: "fake_answer", answerText: "Because"},
        {id: "argumentative_answer", answerText: "Why not?"}
      ]
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<div id="questionsContainer"></div>
```